# How do I update a published widget on bigcommerce?

Tags: widget, bigcommerce

I recently published a widget on our bigcommerce site but made some changes to the code from my local afterward. How do I update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways in which we can do this. One is via the [update widget API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-content/widgets/widget#update-a-widget) and pass the code there. The other is to get familiar with the [widget builder](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/store-management/widgets/widget-builder), try it out in your staging store and then start working with that.